# Difference between Google Pay Api and Android Pay Api

Tags: android, google-pay

What is the difference between Google Pay Api and Android Pay Api. What I know is using Android Pay Api we use do both payment and adding loyalty cards. Now google has introduced Google Pay Api. Is it replacement for Android Pay Api?

Comment: just google: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Android-Pay-and-Google-Wallet

Answer (score 2):

Google just announced that it’s combining all of its different payment services, including Android Pay and Google Wallet, into one unified service, simply called Google Pay.

With the new system, payment information saved in your Google account will be available everywhere you use Google products: in Chrome for web purchases, in YouTube for renewing your subscriptions, in apps on Android for in-app purchases, and at retail outlets with NFC payments.

**Reference link** -- [Google Pay](https://www.blog.google/topics/shopping-payments/announcing-google-pay/)

Comment: What about Android Pay

Comment: The same functionality that you used through Android Pay before, is made available through Google Pay now.